# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure Connection reset

Tags: mysql, hikaricp, quartz, proxysql

got a problem.log as below

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 7,202,037 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 7,202,037 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectSchedulerStateRecords(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2994)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.findFailedInstances(JobStoreSupport.java:3384)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.clusterCheckIn(JobStoreSupport.java:3470)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doCheckin(JobStoreSupport.java:3330)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3935)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$ClusterManager.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3972)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 7,202,037 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 7,202,037 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor124.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:546)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:710)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:649)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:951)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:930)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:540)
```

1.I never set a parameter 7200 second ,the most familiar parameter is linux default tcp_keepalive_time(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time)
2.base the error stack Quartz framework call findFailedInstances methor to check other Instance alive or not,it can not take 2 hourse(7200 second) long
3.Mysql **wait_timeout** is set 8 hourse,hikari **MAX_LIFETIME** using default parameter(1800 second)
4.those error came out suddently ,most of the time the application is normal

my question is what reason cause this error ,how can i find the true reason or how can i prove that is not my application problem.i doubt the **Proxy sql** side has kill the connection without notice but i'm not falimilar with proxy sql can not solve it

any advice will be apreciate.